# Determine if user is signed in or not by other user in parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my game, I need to do a check to see if another player is signed in or not, if they are then I cannot attack them. Right now I'm doing that by setting a Boolean when the user signs in, and then setting it to NO with `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but I've been told this sometimes doesn't run especially if the App crashes.

So my question is, are there any other ways to determine if a player is signed in or not?

Comment: Surelynyou want to consult the server to find out if other users are signed in?

Comment: When the user signs in, I set a Boolean on the server to YES, but the problem is knowing when they have stopped playing because applicationDidEnterBackground doesn't always run.

Answer (score 2):

`applicationDidEnterBackground` will generally be called. If you're worried about crashes you can implement an uncaught exception handler. You can also consider having a, relatively infrequent, keep alive update sent to the server periodically and auto-logout the user if it isn't received.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm going to do, use some kind of inactivity check.